# Adding Let's Encrypt certificates to debian:9 docker image

Tags: docker, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I want to build an image based on `debian:9` and add let's encrypt certificates from the following links:

https://letsencrypt.org/certs/isrgrootx1.pem.txt

https://letsencrypt.org/certs/trustid-x3-root.pem.txt

Afaik, these should be converted to `.crt` format so I run:

```
▶ openssl x509 -in isrgrootx1.pem -inform PEM -out isrgrootx1.crt
▶ openssl x509 -in trustid-x3-root.pem -inform PEM -out trustid-x3-root.crt
```

Then I build an image using the following `Dockerfile`

```
FROM debian:9

RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/ca-certificates/extra


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install ca-certificates -y --no-install-recommends

COPY isrgrootx1.crt /usr/share/ca-certificates/extra/isrgrootx1.crt
COPY trustid-x3-root.crt /usr/share/ca-certificates/extra/trustid-x3-root.crt

RUN update-ca-certificates
```

however, at the end of the build I see no extra certificates are added:

```
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
```

What is more when listing them inside a running container using [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/97252/136100) command

```
awk -v cmd='openssl x509 -noout -subject' '
    /BEGIN/{close(cmd)};{print | cmd}' < /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

I don't see any `Let's Encrypt` certificates installed.

Am I missing any step?

Comment: are the files in the folder where Dockerfile is ? They are not added to .dockerignore or covered by some other exclusion rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the path you want is `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`. The following showed 2 certificates being added:

```
FROM debian:9

RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
      ca-certificates \
      openssl \
 && mkdir -p /usr/local/share/ca-certificates

ADD https://letsencrypt.org/certs/isrgrootx1.pem.txt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/isrgrootx1.pem
ADD https://letsencrypt.org/certs/trustid-x3-root.pem.txt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/trustid-x3-root.pem

RUN cd /usr/local/share/ca-certificates \
 && openssl x509 -in isrgrootx1.pem -inform PEM -out isrgrootx1.crt \
 && openssl x509 -in trustid-x3-root.pem -inform PEM -out trustid-x3-root.crt \
 && update-ca-certificates
```

Note, the certificates you downloaded do not say lets encrypt in the subject:

```
root@4544afdd06e3:/# openssl x509 -noout -subject </usr/local/share/ca-certificates/isrgrootx1.pem
subject=C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
root@4544afdd06e3:/# openssl x509 -noout -subject </usr/local/share/ca-certificates/trustid-x3-root.pem
subject=O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
```

Comment: thanks; any idea why the following executed on a running container built with the above `Dockerfile` shows no output? `root@43b7414439d4:/# awk -v cmd='openssl x509 -noout -subject' '
    /BEGIN/{close(cmd)};{print | cmd}' < /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt | grep -i encry`

Comment: never mind, it appears as `Internet Security Research Group` and not as `Let's Encrypt` or sth

Comment: Installing trustid-x3-root does not make sense any more, because it expired on September 30, 2021